# Wrap an Operator overloading method

Tags: c++, c++-cli, operator-overloading

How do I wrap a method which performs *operator overloading* in unmanaged C++ code using C++/CLI?

I am working for an organisation and I don't have much access to their source code and hence don't have much idea about what the operator overloading function does exactly. So is there a way to wrap this method and not redefine it in C++/CLI?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301733.aspx is probably a good startingpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand but, wrapping native code means covering and executing it in a managed function. For example you want to wrap this class:

```
//Native code
class NativeClass
{
  std::vector<int> data;
public:
  int operator[] (int index)
  {
    return data[index];
  }
}


//Managed code
public ref class ManagedClass
{
  NativeClass * nativeClass;
public:
  property int default [int]
  {
    int get (int index) {   return (*nativeClass)[index];   }
  }

  int GetData(int index)
  {
    return (*nativeClass)[index];
  }
}
```

Here you go, both by defining an indexer and a function you wrap the native overloaded operator.

Short answer you have to redefine and determine how you will expose the native functions to managed environment. This is what wrapping means.